# Absolute position div prevents td from going to 0 height in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a `<td>` that contains a `<div>`, where the div is absolutely positioned. The `<td>` is then set to 0 height by setting the `height, line-height, border, and padding-top/padding-bottom` css properties to 0.

The result, when combined with a number of other elements and javascript that have no bearing on the issue, is a header row that can float nicely above the table while staying properly aligned with the table columns.

This works properly in every browser and OS I have been able to test with (Safari, Chrome, IE on Windows and Mac), EXCEPT Firefox. In firefox the `<tr>` containing the 0 height `<td>`'s in question shows up as 4 pixels high - but only if the `<div>` inside has a `position` attribute of `absolute` or `fixed`. If I use a `position` of `relative`, for example, the row properly collapses to 0px high. Of course, I need a position of `absolute` on the div to make everything else work.

How can I get firefox as well to properly collapse the `<tr>`/`<td>`?

html:

```
<table id="zeroHeight">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Some Content that should disappear
            <div>Content that should have no background</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#zeroHeight tr{
    background-color:lightblue;
}

#zeroHeight tr td{
    height:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    line-height:0px;
    border:0px;
    color:transparent;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#zeroHeight td div{
    position:absolute;
    color:black;
}
```

NOTE: The issue here is NOT with the positioning of the absolute DIV. This works fine, thus the reason I didn't bother including any positioning in the example. The issue is that the `<TD>/<TR>` does not properly collapse down to zero height, as indicated by the visible background color applied to the `<tr>`

EDIT: The issue here is the non-zero height of the `td`/`tr`, not the visible background color. The background color on the row is simply an easy way to make the issue visible.

Comment: Have you tried setting the margin to 0 as well? Might also have to do with certain display interpretations having white space (as present with inline-block elements). See https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Also might be relevant: https://davidwalsh.name/table-cell-position-absolute

Comment: You could set `font-size: 0` on the `td`, but you'd then need to explicitly set a font size on the `div`:  https://jsfiddle.net/enpoe4yd/

Comment: @RickHitchcock: Setting font size to 0 could potentially mess up the sizing of the table column, depending on if the content of the table body is wider than the header cell being hidden. The width needs to remain unmolested, which means the font size needs to remain unchanged.

Comment: @smrubin: Just tried setting margin (on both the div and td), didn't appear to make any difference. The link you gave appears to be related to absolute positioning a div within a td, i.e. getting it positioned where you want it. I have no problem with the positioning, only the sizing of the parent td is at issue.

Comment: Gotcha.  So while `Some Content that should disappear` *should* disappear, it should still count when determining the width of the column.  Tricky.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Exactly. And it works beautifully in every browser but Firefox :-) I may just have to live with it, maybe write some firefox specific javascript to try to somewhat hide the remaining 4-pixel `<tr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not style `tr` and `td` like that. Why not wrapping the invisible content in an extra div and hide that?

**HTML:**

```
<table id="zeroHeight">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="invisible">Some Content that should disappear</div>
            <div class="visible">Content that should have no background</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
#zeroHeight tr td div.invisible{
    background-color:lightblue;
}

#zeroHeight tr td div.invisible {
    height:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    line-height:0px;
    border:0px;
    color:transparent;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#zeroHeight td div.visible{
    position:absolute;
    color:black;
}
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/2j2s9jys/1/

Comment: That hides the problem (by moving the background color to a div which does in fact wind up with zero height, as it should), but doesn't fix it: the `td`/`tr` still has a non-zero height due to the absolute positioned div inside (see https://jsfiddle.net/2j2s9jys/2/). The example I gave was designed to highlight the problem, not be 100% accurate as to the goal. That said, interestingly, your solution does reduce the height of the `td`/`tr` to 2px rather than 4 (apparently, more testing is in order), so it is still an improvement.

Comment: Oh, wait: looks like this might work after all - I just needed to add `line-height:0px;` and `padding:0px;` to the td itself, and violà: the `td`/`tr` disappears (https://jsfiddle.net/2j2s9jys/3/)! I think that should do it. I still need to test to make sure that the table size correctly continues to respect the contents of the "invisible" div, but it looks promising. Thanks!